# How can i avoid loading same image again?

Tags: jquery, html

Whenever a user post comment it create elements dynamically using jquery with thumb image. Every time it post a comment it loads the same thumb nail again and again.

```
<img alt='64x64' class='media-object user-thumb' style='width: 64px; height: 64px;' src='"+v.userThumb+"'/>
```

How can i avoid loading same image again?

Comment: Normally this should be handled by the browser cache. Is the image cachable?

Comment: http://gtmetrix.com/add-expires-headers.html

Comment: its just a png image

Comment: thumb image is dynamic i.e if user changes profile pics it should reflect immediatly. no-profile-image thumb image is fixed

Answer (score -1):

If you wnat to force the browser to request data for the server again, you can just append any random or incremental querystring to it:

```
<img alt='64x64' class='media-object user-thumb' style='width: 64px; height: 64px;' src='"+v.userThumb + "&date=" + new Date().getTime() + "'/>
```

This will force the browser to request the image to the server again.

Comment: Question is about the opposite!

Comment: @TheStoryCoder I disagree, from the question comments and from the question itself I understood the image `src` is always the same because it's dynamically generated in the back end, so if user want to force browser to make a new request and then get a new image he should add a random query string to slightly change the URL. As no one else provided any other answer I understand that at least some people agrees to my point of view

Comment: I guess the question is actually quite unclear...! Can see it can be understood both ways...